# Ordinal of a new column in snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to add a new column to an existing Table in snowflake, how to specify where to add the column. I tried the below query,

```
ALTER TABLE MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE 
ADD COLUMN MY_NEW_COLUMN NUMBER(38,0) AFTER MY_OLD_COLUMN1;
```

`AFTER` keyword doesn't works with Snowflake. Any suggestions on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Today Snowflake does not have the ability to specify the position of the added column. It is in the list of future improvements, but we don't have an ETA on this yet.

Of course there are various solutions that might help, e.g. views, but I agree we'd ideally add this ability.

Let us know if we can help with anything else.

Comment: Six years on, is this still true?

Comment: Looks like its still doesn't allow it :(